# Elasticsearch, Kibana group by/aggregate documents

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, aggregate, kibana

In an Elastisearch index I am collecting ratings from users. That is, in index
*localhost:9200/content_ratings/* we have documents of type *content_rating*. This document type has the following fields:

- title
- autor
- url
- rating
- ratedBy

Let's say our index contains the following docs:

```
{
  "title": "Data Quality", "author": "John Queue", "url": "/news/2015/data-quality", "rating":3, "ratedBy": "userA"
}
{
  "title": "Data Quality", "author": "John Queue", "url": "/news/2015/data-quality", "rating":1, "ratedBy": "userB"
}
{
  "title": "User Story Estimations", "author": "Abby Edye", "url": "/news/2014/story-splitting", "rating":5, "ratedBy": "userC"
}
```

I need a report (Elasticsearch 1.0, Kibana 3) which shows each rated item and computes its average rating. So we need to 'Group by url' and have something like this:

```
"title": "Data Quality", "author": "John Queue", "url": "/news/2015/data-quality", "avgRating":2
"title": "User Story Estimations", "author": "Abby Edye", "url": "/news/2014/story-splitting", "avgRating":5
```

a) is there a way in ES to use 'group by' equivalent constructs?

b) is there a way in ES to query the results returned by (another) query from a)? - I am asking this because from the aggregated results, in another report(Kibana panel) I would need to count how may items were rated good(4) or excellent(5)?

I am new to ES/kibana and after a lot of googling the closest to my requirement are these links:
 [How do I group documents in elasticsearch by a single field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182791/how-do-i-group-documents-in-elasticsearch-by-a-single-field?rq=1)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

I have tried *terms facet* which is implicitly supported by my current set-up(ES 1.0, kibana3) but is nowhere near what I need...

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use "aggs" in elasticsearch to perform groupby action.

I have a sample here you can get idea how to make yours: 
here I have used nested aggrigations (groupby) to get the average age of people in each nationality which are in special age blocks.

```
GET customer/_search
{
"size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_state": {
            "range": {
                "field": "age",
                "ranges": [
                        { "from": 20,"to": 40 },
                        { "from": 40, "to": 60 },
                        { "from": 60, "to": 100}
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {  
                "group_by_nationality": {
                    "terms": { 
                        "field": "nationality.keyword"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "average_age": {
                            "avg": {
                                "field": "age"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }              
    }
}
```